# tar utime from docker-on-windows does not work

Tags: docker, tar, docker-for-windows

I am trying to do some builds from docker (yocto specifically), and I would like to be able to run it and have the output be in the Windows filesystem. However, no matter I do, `utime` does not work from the docker container.

(Note that all is fine if I change the output directories to be inside the docker container, instead of two a docker volume mounted to local windows filesystem)

Specifically, from `tar` (extract):  `Cannot utime: Operation not permitted` (not that adding `-m` works around this, but I do not have control over all the places tar is called)

Everything I read about this error points to a file permissions issue, but I have tried running docker from a PowerShell as Administrator, and it does not solve the problem.

Is this just a deficiency of the Windows filesystem (NTFS) or is there a way to configure docker volumes to have the required permissions to set utime.

Comment: Same issue here. Any news?